# Hacer que una variable sea igual a otra

Tags: c#

Se que posiblemente no se entienda mucho lo que quiero hacer. Tengo una sola variable en card in muestraCards y tres en carti in playerCards. Y yo necesito que si las dos condiciones son correctas para una carta esa carta (carti) pase a tener la misma valor que card. Pero no me deja porque dice "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

```
foreach(var card in muestraCards)
{
   foreach(var carti in playerCards)
   {
       int i = 0;

       if (card == "O2" || card == "O4" || card == "O5" || card == "OQ" || card == "OJ")
       {
           if (carti == "OK")
           {  
              playerCards[i] = card;
           }
        }

        i ++;
        Debug.Log($"Carta de la persona: {carti}");
    }
}
```

Comment: No puedes modificar la variable que usas para el bucle.  Porque no guardas los valores en otro array?

Comment: No sabria como hacer eso

Comment: Limitaciones del forEach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Porque no usas el bucle `for` para recorrer todo el array en lugar de usar `foreach`?:

```c#
foreach(var card in muestraCards){
   for(int i=0;i<playerCards.Length; i++){
       if (card == "O2" || card == "O4" || card == "O5" || card == "OQ" || card == "OJ"){
           if (playerCards[i]== "OK"){  
              playerCards[i] = card;
           }
        }
        //Y si quieres usar la variable carti:
        string carti=playerCards[i];
        Debug.Log($"Carta de la persona: {playerCards[i]}");
    }
}
```

Solo use el atributo `Length` para conocer el tamaño del array y con la variable `i` recorremos el array hasta que valga lo mismo que `Length`